# EditText setSpan for special characters

Tags: android

How to set span for special characters, like \n \t \r , etc ? Right now if i do this:

```
getText().setSpan(DynamicListView.mBackgroundColor, start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure I understand the question, as the special characters `'\n'` nd `'\r'` are line breaks, so how could they be styled as they will be invisible?

That said, here is a method for styling certain `char`s in an `EditText`. You can add as many chars as you like to the end of the method and any instances of those characters will be styled.

```
//...
editText.setText(getSpannedText(editText.getText(), `u`, `r`));
//...
private static SpannableString getSpannedText(String text, char... triggers) {

    SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString(text);

    for (int i = 0; i < spanString.length(); i++) {
        for (char trigger : triggers) {
            if (spanString.charAt(i) == trigger) {
                spanString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.CYAN), i, i+1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
        }
    }

    return spanString;

}
```

Comment: Yes, i am using nearly same solution. Yes, \n and \r are invisible, but \t is visible and looks like space, but Span is not working exactly for this character "\t"

Comment: @user3901709 Ahh, I see. Is it practical to replace the `'\t'` character with something else, like a space, prior to setting the span? i.e. `string = string.replace('\t', ' ');`

Comment: Unfortunately can't do this, bcz later i need to save this data to file (it is file reader), and \t will be missed then

Answer (score 0):

Fixed on my side by Draw functions, here is code of EditText:

```
if(getText().toString().substring(start,end).indexOf("\t")>=0
            || getText().toString().substring(start,end).indexOf("\n")>=0
            || getText().toString().substring(start,end).indexOf("\r")>=0) {
        TextPaint paint = new TextPaint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(mBackgroundColor);
        paint.bgColor = mBackgroundColor;

        Layout layout = getLayout();
        int line = layout.getLineForOffset(start);
        int baseline = layout.getLineBaseline(line);
        int ascent = layout.getLineAscent(line);
        float x = layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(start);
        float y = baseline + ascent;

        Rect rect = new Rect();
        //rect.set(start, 0, Math.round(layout.getSecondaryHorizontal(end)), getLineHeight()+5);
        rect.set(start, 0, Math.round(layout.getSecondaryHorizontal(end)), getLineHeight()+5);
        rect.offset(Math.round(x), Math.round(y));

        Log.d("debug","tabs " + rect.toString());
        canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
    }
```